# Xcode #pragma mark doesn't work for me

Tags: xcode

In Xcode method listings (activated via Ctrl-2), the method names are always listed in alphabetical order.  If I do:

#pragma mark -

#pragma mark TableView delegates

...table view delegates here...

The listing doesn't show the separator or "Table View delegates" right before the table view delegate methods, it's showing them at the bottom of the list.  But I have seen it working in other people's Xcode IDE.  Any idea why I am getting this?

Comment: If the answers thus far don't help, post a screen shot. It will be easier for us to help with a screen shot (or sseveral)...  Good luck...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might have "Sort list alphabetically" on in XCode Preferences under Code Sense. Uncheck this option and it should work. See [this article about #pragma mark for details](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/xcode/xcode-and-pragma-mark.html).